# Prove that this number is less than $1$,

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

a) Prove that, if $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers and $|w| = 1$, then

$$\frac{|z-w|}{|1- \bar z w|} = 1$$

b) Prove that, if $|z|<1$, $|w|<1$, then

$$\frac{|z-w|}{|1- \bar z w|} < 1$$

I have proved part(a), but am stuck on part(b).  I tried using triangle inequalities but am getting not-good-enough upper bounds, e.g., a bound of $2$ instead of $1$.

Any hints or solutions for part(b) are welcome and appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Both have been asked before many times.

Comment: Hi @GitGud, I was not aware -- do you have a link?  I'll try searching on MSE now, too.  Thanks,

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423134/inequality-holding-for-complex-numbers-in-the-unit-disk

Comment: Hi @r9m, do you possibly have another link?  I am not sure why he (or she) squares the modulus and multiplies it with another factor - I don't know what the motivation for it is... of, course, for part(a) that I was able to prove, squaring the modulus, and using z$\bar z$ was essential, but I don't see how that is helpful for part(b).  Thanks,

Comment: @r9m Good to see you back!

Comment: @LebronJames The squaring was essential for the linked question, keeping in mind that $\displaystyle u = \frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}} \implies \bar{u} = \frac{\bar{z}-\bar{w}}{1-\bar{z}w}$, and on multiplication yields $\displaystyle |u|^2 = \frac{z\bar{z} - z\bar{w} - w\bar{z} + w\bar{w}}{1- z\bar{w} - w\bar{z}+z\bar{z}w\bar{w}} \implies 1-|u|^2 = \frac{(1-|z|^2)(1-|w|^2)}{|1-z\bar{w}|^2} > 0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV :-) $\,\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (b), we prove $|1-\overline{z}w|^2 > |z-w|^2$

Left-hand side is:

$\begin{align}
|1-\overline{z}w|^2 = (1-\overline{z}w)(1-\overline{\overline{z}w}) = (1-\overline{z}w)(1-z\overline{w}) &= -\overline{z}w-z\overline{w}+1+z \overline{z}w \overline{w} \\
&= -(\overline{z}w+z\overline{w}) + (1+|z|^2|w|^2)
\end{align}$

Right-hand side is:

$\begin{align}
|z-w|^2 = (z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w}) &= -\overline{z}w-z\overline{w}+z\overline{z}+w\overline{w} \\
&= -(\overline{z}w+z\overline{w}) + (|z|^2+|w|^2)
\end{align}$

Now we need only show that $1+|z|^2|w|^2 > |z|^2+|w|^2$

We are given $|z|,|w|<1$ so $|z|^2,|w|^2<1$.

Hence

$\begin{align}
(1-|z|^2)(1-|w|^2) > 0 &\implies \\
1+|z|^2|w|^2-|z|^2-|w|^2 > 0 &\implies \\
1+|z|^2|w|^2 > |z|^2+|w|^2  
\end{align}$

as required.

---

Notes:

- Since $|v|\ge0$ for any complex (or real) v, we can prove desired results for $|*|^2$ instead of $|*|$
- $|v|^2 = v\overline{v}$ is guaranteed to be $\ge 0$
- there was no need to do anything further with the $\overline{z}w+z\overline{w}$ term